# Angular version not showing "ng --version"

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface, node-modules

I was stuck in installing angular, I have installed angular globally. When i try to find version it is not showing version and showing some warnings related to optional dependency. I'm getting only Angular Cli by typing command `ng --version`. also Im getting problems in creating new Project. so may be angular is not properly set up. 
[image]

Comment: if you have Node.js correctly installed, go to the command line and put in:
node -v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your command prompt color to black/blue, It is probaby because text color is white

Comment: OMG :O 
Thanks man I was stuck since yesterday and I reinstalled several times and cleaned cache but got same.